# Need for transacional outbox pattern on microservices

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, messaging, messagebroker

I see a recommendation for using the transactional outbox pattern (https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) for scenarios in which a message should be published to a broker after some change in the database, so it can be "ACID". My question is: why not put the message publish **inside** the transaction like this?

```
try {
   beginTransaction()
   saveStuff()
   publishMessage() 
   commitTransaction()
} catch() {
   rollbackTransaction()
}
```

This way, whenever the message publish fails, the transaction will be rolled back. I see only one issue: you may not want to rollback the transaction when the message publish fails, trying again later. Are there other issues with this approach?

Comment: Sometime after asking this question, I found this Udi Dahan video about reliable messaging without distributed transaction. I think might be useful for others with the same question: https://vimeo.com/channels/1105173/111998645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publishMessage can work (the message is sent) but the commitTransaction might fail (eg lost connection to the database or the application crashes after sending message and before calling commit)